# Display User details in Flutter Home page from Django Rest Framework Data using FutureBuilder approach

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

In my Flutter app I have home page which appears after logging in and I want to add the first & last name of the logged in user.

I have created a file under the name of config.dart which is showing the url that I want to get the user details from which:

```
class Config {
  static const String apiURL = "http://00.0.0.00:0000/";
  static const String userProfileAPI = "api/dj-rest-auth/user/";
```

Also I created a model for the user_profile.dart as following:

```
class User_Profile {
  int? pk;
  String? username;
  String? email;
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;

  User_Profile(
      {this.pk, this.username, this.email, this.firstName, this.lastName});

  User_Profile.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    pk = json['pk'];
    username = json['username'];
    email = json['email'];
    firstName = json['first_name'];
    lastName = json['last_name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['pk'] = this.pk;
    data['username'] = this.username;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['first_name'] = this.firstName;
    data['last_name'] = this.lastName;
    return data;
  }
}
```

in my api_service.dart

```
  static Future<String> getUserProfile() async {
    var loginDetails = await SharedService.loginDetails();

    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ${loginDetails!.key}'
    };

    var url = Uri.parse(Config.apiURL + Config.userProfileAPI);
    var response = await client.get(
      url,
      headers: requestHeaders,
    );
    print(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return response.body;
      print(response.body);
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }
```

My question how can I proceed forward to get the data and show it in the home page in the following section of the homepage:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

//................reduced unrelated code.......................

Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            // TODO Change to User Name
                            "Hi, [firstname] [lastname]!",
                            style: Styles.headLineStyle1,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
```

**Required outcome:** I want to be able to get the information of the logged in user from Django Rest Framework and add his first name and last name in the home page. I am doing this for learning purposes to be able to implement the same concept further.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like this

```
FutureBuilder<User_Profile>(
          future: getUserProfile(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: size.height / 15,
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: UserImage(),
                    ),
                    Poppins(
                        size: 20, text: "Hi" + snapshot.data!.firstname +snapshot.data!.lastname, color: blue),
                  
                  ]);
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }
            // By default show a loading spinner.
            return const LoadingAnimation();
          },
        ),
```

`Poppins` is a custom Text Widget .

`getUserProfile()` is your API call

Comment: I am getting all errors because of Poppins and size box as well as loading animation

Comment: Use Text Widget Instead of Poppins

Comment: Use CircularProgressIndiactor for Loading Animation